# (c++) Cannot get void functions to work, having trouble with a few lines inside of the main.cpp as well

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble with the code that I've put below. The void functions seem to be fine, but they aren't working. I'm not sure what I've done wrong, so any help is appreciated. Also, I don't know how to use an if statement to call in questions from an infile for two players, as shown below this. Please, I have to turn it in at 11pm 12/3 and any help is appreciated. I've already been working on it for 5 hours now

if statement here to display odd number of questions to player1 and even number of questions to player2, make sure to add the correct score for respective player by calling the function upDateScoreDouble

```
void getHistory (playerHistory pHist[], int loopy, ifstream& inQuest)
    {
        int i = 0 ;
        loopy = 22 ;
        while( i < loopy, i++)
        {
        inQuest >> pHist[i].alias1 ;
        inQuest >> pHist[i].score ;
        inQuest >> pHist[i].difficulty ;
        inQuest >> pHist[i].date ;
        }

        return ;
    }


    void bubblesort (playerHistory pHist[], int length)
    {
        bool swapped = true;
          int j = 0;
          int tmp;
          while (swapped) {
                swapped = false;
                j++;
                for (int i = 0; i < length - j; i++) {
                      if (pHist[i].score > pHist[i + 1].score) {
                            tmp = pHist[i].score;
                            pHist[i].score = pHist[i + 1].score;
                            pHist[i + 1].score = tmp;
                            swapped = true;
                      }
                }
          }
    return ;
    }

///3.3.6 create a loop to call the getQuestion function for each question
            for(int loopy=1; loopy<=numQuestions; loopy++)
                {

                ///3.3.6.2 getQuestion function call
                    getQuestion(gameQ, numQuestions, inQuest) ;
                ///3.3.6.1 if statement here to display odd number of questions to player1 and even number of questions to player2
                ///make sure to add the correct score for respective player by calling the function upDateScoreDouble
                if(loopy < numQuestions)
                {
                    inQuest >> gameQ[loopy].question;
                    cout << gameQ[loopy].question ;
                    cout << gameQ[loopy].answer ;
                    cout << gameQ[loopy].ans1 ;
                    cout << gameQ[loopy].ans2 ;
                    cout << gameQ[loopy].ans3 ;
                    cout << gameQ[loopy].ans4 ;

                }


                }   ///end of for loop of number of questions
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `getHistory` function it looks like you want a `for` loop instead.

Because the expression `i < loopy, i++` evaluates `i < loopy` and then *throws away the result*.

Instead the condition of the loop is `i++`, and since it's `0` in the first iteration the result is false and the loop never happens.

Read more about the comma-operator [in e.g. this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

You probably want something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 22; ++i) { ... }
```